# Send IFormFile back from controller - Asp Net Core

Tags: file, asp.net-core, upload, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm uploading some files using IFormFile interface

```xml
    <input required asp-for="FeaturedPhoto" type="file" />
```

The file is being uploaded correctly, but now I would like to load this back into my model so it can be used in an Edit view.

The image is being uploaded in the server, only the path and name are being saved into the DB.

```cs
    obj.FeaturedPhoto = new FormFile(); // Need help building this
```

Regards,

Comment: I don't think you can load the files in to a form, you can however display that file by exposing a stream, what kind of file is it?

Comment: I'm working with images

Comment: Not what you are asking for, but I recommend displaying the image, and just having a checkbox if someone wants to override the image. Store your path to the image in a hidden input field.

Comment: why not simply send back base64-encoded characters to client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the uploaded file as base64 encoded string:

```cs
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(string))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        // your other code
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.CopyTo(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                return new OkObjectResult(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

On the client side you can show the image like so:

```xml
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="test image" />
```

To use the above you need to know the ContentType. You can find this by using:

```cs
    file.ContentType
```

Comment: @Isotov have you tried this? Have you solved your problem?